# How can I start an X11 session on my headless Fedora 13 server?

Tags: fedora, x11, headless

I have a small home server using Fedora 13 as operating system.

Since the upgrade to Fedora 13 I cannot start the X11 server. (I need it to use vnc)

When I try to start the server, both the **[nouveau](http://nouveau.freedesktop.org/wiki/)** and the original NVIDIA driver claim that there's no physical monitor attached (which is true) and that the X server cannot start because the initial display modes cannot be probed.

I tried to manually add the display modes to `xorg.conf` but they seem to be ignored.

Some forums suggest to simply use the VESA driver in this situation, but since I can't get it run either (different, more obscure message) I want to get it working with the nouveau driver as a matter of principle.

Temporarily attaching a monitor would mean a lot of work for me (> 1 hour and currently it's almost 35°C/95°F in my home) I want to try that only if that definitely fixes the problem and stays that way if I remove the monitor again)

How can I make the driver work without having a physical monitor attached?

Thank you for your time and your help!

Answer (score 5):

One option would be to set up X forwarding over ssh and run an X server on your local machine with the apps running on the server.

Enable X forwarding on the server (`/etc/ssh/sshd_config`):

```
X11Forwarding yes
AllowAgentForwarding yes
```

Enable X forwarding on the client (`/etc/ssh/ssh_config` ):

```
ForwardAgent yes
ForwardX11 yes
```

- [A tutorial](https://web.archive.org/web/20121011040539/http://www.vanemery.com/Linux/XoverSSH/X-over-SSH2.html)
- [Enabling X11 forwarding in SSH](https://www.ssh.com/academy/ssh/config#enabling-x11-forwarding-and-agent-forwarding)
- [HowTo](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/XDMCP-HOWTO/ssh.html)
- [Using XMing and PuTTY in Windows](http://www.cs.caltech.edu/courses/cs11/misc/xwindows.html)

Comment: +1 Until now I didn't knew there was a free Windows X server and never got the Cygwin one to work. XMing works flawlessly and out of the box. But I don't accept your answer, because it only circumvents the original problems. Many thanks nevertheless!

Comment: @DR: I suppose a VGA dummy plug or a [product like this](http://www.drbottkg.com/prod/ghead.html) would be the same issue as connecting a monitor (heat and time).

Comment: This is a neat little app: http://mobaxterm.mobatek.net/ - no fiddling around with XMing and PuTTY or Cygwin which I could never get working satisfactorily (credit goes to Sam who was one of the SO devs who mentioned it in the comments: http://samsaffron.com/archive/2013/05/03/eliminating-my-trivial-inconveniences)

Comment: The top two links are broken. Please include the relevant information in the response, otherwise this happens.

Answer (score 3):

Another option is running GDM over VNC, which will give you a GDM login window over VNC. See [Vnc & Gdm](http://fedoraforum.org/forum/archive/index.php/t-1606.html)

Answer (score 3):

Found it [here](http://www.spinics.net/lists/xorg/msg51951.html), credits to Ata Roboubi.

Using the official nvidia driver, with "ConnectedMonitor" and "UseEDID"=False options as below, the driver will be forced to use the CRT-0 output without checking any EDID data.

Even if you let a configured mode string into the file, it will fall back to 1024x768.

/etc/X11/xorg.conf:

```
Section "Device"
        Identifier     "Configured Video Device"
        Driver         "nvidia"
        Option         "ConnectedMonitor" "CRT-0"
        Option         "UseEDID"     "FALSE"
EndSection
```

Resulting Xorg.0.log:

```
(**) Aug 12 19:35:46 NVIDIA(0): ConnectedMonitor string: "CRT-0"
(**) Aug 12 19:35:46 NVIDIA(0): Ignoring EDIDs
(II) Aug 12 19:35:47 NVIDIA(GPU-0): Not probing EDID on CRT-0.
(II) Aug 12 19:35:47 NVIDIA(0): NVIDIA GPU GeForce GTS 450 (GF116) at PCI:3:0:0 (GPU-0)
(--) Aug 12 19:35:47 NVIDIA(0): Memory: 1048576 kBytes
(--) Aug 12 19:35:47 NVIDIA(0): VideoBIOS: 70.26.26.00.01
(II) Aug 12 19:35:47 NVIDIA(0): Detected PCI Express Link width: 16X
(--) Aug 12 19:35:47 NVIDIA(0): Interlaced video modes are supported on this GPU
(--) Aug 12 19:35:47 NVIDIA(0): Connected display device(s) on GeForce GTS 450 at PCI:3:0:0
(--) Aug 12 19:35:47 NVIDIA(0):     CRT-0
(--) Aug 12 19:35:47 NVIDIA(0): CRT-0: 400.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
(II) Aug 12 19:35:47 NVIDIA(0): Display Device found referenced in MetaMode: CRT-0
(II) Aug 12 19:35:47 NVIDIA(0): Assigned Display Device: CRT-0
(WW) Aug 12 19:35:47 NVIDIA(0): No valid modes for "CRT-0:1280x1024"; removing.
(WW) Aug 12 19:35:47 NVIDIA(0):
(WW) Aug 12 19:35:47 NVIDIA(0): Unable to validate any modes; falling back to the default mode
(WW) Aug 12 19:35:47 NVIDIA(0):     "nvidia-auto-select".
(WW) Aug 12 19:35:47 NVIDIA(0):
(II) Aug 12 19:35:47 NVIDIA(0): Validated modes:
(II) Aug 12 19:35:47 NVIDIA(0):     "nvidia-auto-select"
(II) Aug 12 19:35:47 NVIDIA(0): Virtual screen size determined to be 1024 x 768
(WW) Aug 12 19:35:47 NVIDIA(0): Unable to get display device CRT-0's EDID; cannot compute DPI
(WW) Aug 12 19:35:47 NVIDIA(0):     from CRT-0's EDID.
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want a persistent session that's there even when you're not connected over SSH, you can use [Xpra](http://xpra.org/).

You can also use [Xvnc](http://www.physnet.uni-hamburg.de/physnet/vnc/man/Xvnc.html), which will give you something similar, but probably a bit simpler, with the usual "virtual desktop".

You can also use [Xvfb](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xvfb). This is a bit more versatile than Xvnc since you can decide yourself how to connect (Xvnc implies VNC usage).